# Adding a signature form field to a page it's visible in the last page also

Tags: c#, .net, itext, itext7

I'm trying to put signature form fields in a given position at specific pages using iText for .NET (v7.0.4). The code I'm working on is the following:

```
public static void test()
    {
        using (PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(@"c:\temp\pippo.pdf")))
        {
            //Add some blank pages
            pdfDoc.AddNewPage();
            pdfDoc.AddNewPage();
            pdfDoc.AddNewPage();

            //Instantiate a Signature Form Field using factory
            PdfSignatureFormField sgnField = 
                PdfFormField.CreateSignature(pdfDoc, new Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 100));

            //setting name and page
            sgnField.SetFieldName("pluto");
            sgnField.SetPage(1);

            //Adding to AcroForm
            PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDoc, true).AddField(sgnField);
        }
    }
```

The output document (pippo.pdf) has the signature field in first page and that's the expected behavior. The issue is that I can see the signature field even in the last page (the third page, in this case).

Moreover, if I remove the last page, by calling `pdfDoc.RemovePage(3);`, the signature field disappear even from the first page.

The question is: how to make signature form fields not replicated in the last page? Any suggestion is really well accepted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `AddField(PdfFormField field)` is documented as

```
 * This method adds the field to the last page in the document.
 * If there's no pages, creates a new one.
```

Thus, you first assign your field to the first page using

```
sgnField.SetPage(1)
```

and then also to the last one using

```
PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDoc, true).AddField(sgnField);
```

You should use `AddField(PdfFormField field, PdfPage page)` instead:

```
PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDoc, true).AddField(sgnField, pdfDoc.GetFirstPage());
```

---

@iText DEV: When going for PDF2, this should be prevented.

Comment: is it disallowed to assign multiple signature fields with the same name in PDF2?

Comment: @breez *"is it disallowed to assign multiple signature fields with the same name in PDF2?"* - I'm not quite sure what you mean exactly (and one has to know exactly because most variations of duplication are forbidden here). Thus, can you make this a so question in its own right and explain exactly what you mean?

Comment: I was referring to your last remark (@iText DEV) in your answer which to me suggests what the OP is trying to do is against PDF2 spec?

Comment: The OP was not adding *multiple fields with the same name*, he added *a single field to multiple pages*. Which is only allowed if one uses distinct widget annotations of that field on those pages. But since PDF-2.0 (ISO 32000-2), *signature fields shall never refer to more than one annotation.*

Answer (score 0):

Great answer by mkl

Also works for other components you are trying to add to your PDF pages like `PdfTextFormField`:

I fiound the easiest is to then apply the `getPage` as the parameter to ensure I was getting exactly what I expected.

**Example:**

```
PdfAcroForm
    .getAcroForm(pdfDoc, true)
    .addField(myTextArea, pdfDoc.getPage(pageCount));
```